# Changing dimmers to a 3 way switch

Tags: wiring

I have a dimmer that turns on and off in 2 locations,. Want to get rid of dimmers.  How do you make the dimmer a 3 way?  I have 2 black wires.  I want to know where I put the 2 black wires on my new switch. Thanks

Comment: Providing pics of the existing wiring would help considerably. Shut off the power, pull the dimmers out of the boxes and get good, clear, focused pics of the wires and the inside of the box(s). Do _NOT_ disconnect any wires while taking the pics. However, if you want to change a single switch circuit to a double switch circuit, you're probably going to have to pull new wire through the wall to the other switch location.

Comment: @FreeMan I think it's already a 3-way, but OP needs some help navigating the "traveler" issue.

Comment: We're going to need a few pictures of the switch box, dimmer switch and three way switch..... Don't disconnect any wires until  you take pictures.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica my first thought, too. However, "I have **a** dimmer.." - single switch, "in **2** locations" - 3-way switch. Not really sure which it is.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?